# Receiving 400 (Bad Request) on jQuery ajax post to Product Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am receiving 400 (Bad Request) on jQuery ajax post to Product Controller. I am trying to `post` an `array` to my database.

Path `attr`

```
<a id="store-product" data-path="{{ path_for('product.design', {sku: design.sku}) }}">Submit</a>
```

Ajax code

```
/** Call to the Fancy Product Designer **/
fpd = new FancyProductDesigner(_container, pluginOpts);

var _storeProduct = jQuery('#store-product');

_storeProduct.click(function() {
    var url = _storeProduct.attr("data-path");
    var productViews = fpd.getProduct();

    /*******
    //console.log(productViews);
    //Works Fine upto here with the log array below
    //Array[5]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Objectlength: 5__proto__: Array[0]
    *******/

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            action: 'store',
            views: productViews
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if(parseInt(data) > 0) {
                alert('Product with ID ' + data + ' stored!');
            } else {
                alert('Error: ' + data + '');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Not sure what i have wrong here.

Controller Code

```
public function design($sku, Request $request, Response $response) {
    $design = Design::where('sku', $sku)->first();

    if($request->getParam('action') == 'store') {
        $views = $request->getParam('views');

        $design->update([
            'views' => $views
        ]);

        return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('product.get', [
            'sku' => $sku,
        ]));
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Apache Access Log

```
::1 - - [18/Jan/2017:16:27:25 +0700] "POST /projects/GolfBag/public/golf-bags/design/2563901 HTTP/1.1" 400 18 "http://localhost/projects/GolfBag/public/golf-bags/2563901" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Routes

```
$app->get('/golf-bags/{sku}', ['Base\Controllers\ProductController', 'getProducts'])->setName('product.get');
$app->post('/golf-bags/design/{sku}', ['Base\Controllers\ProductController', 'design'])->setName('product.design');
```

Comment: Are you sure the `url` is correct? You can read more here about 400 errors http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html and https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-a-400-bad-request-error-2617988 It can be anything, it can be a server problem etc.

Comment: please provide some debug information. check apache access log, where your script makes calls

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging i found the issue was that the CSRF token is not applied to the post data